# How to install WildFly 8.x service and WildFly 9.x service side by side on one machine?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, wildfly-9

I have installed a WildFly 8.x as a service. Now I need to install a WildFly 9.0 as another service on the same Windows server.  But I get error which said the service already exists.

I have changed the names in the service.bat and I use the "service.bat install" command.

Thanks for your help.

Mai

Answer (score 3):

you need to edit the service.bat file on the wildfly9 folder (scripts/service) and as the file suggests (if you open it) - you need to edit the name.

```
REM Author: Tom Fonteyne
REM
REM ==================================================================
REM If more then one service is needed, copy this file to another name
REM and use unique names for SHORTNAME, DISPLAYNAME, DESCRIPTION
REM ==================================================================
set SHORTNAME=Wildfly
set DISPLAYNAME="Wildfly"
set DESCRIPTION="Wildfly Application Server"
REM =======================================================
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. But I did change the name already. It seems not work.  just because  one is wildfly 8.0 ,another is 9.0?

Comment: r u sure you change the correct file?for the correct server? As far as I know, this particular file has not changed in between these 2 versions

Comment: Hi, I made it work ,finally.     The unique name can not be "wildfly 8.0" and "wildfly 9.0".   It seems the script processor only reads the first word "wildfly" and ignore the "8.0" and "9.0".